# reflecting every schema from postgres DB using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, database-schema

I have an existing database that has two schemas, named `schools` and `students`, contained in an instance of `declarative_base` and through two different classes that inherit from that instance

```
class DirectorioEstablecimiento(Base):
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'schools'}
    __tablename__ = 'addresses'
    # some Columns are defined here
```

and

```
class Matricula(Base):
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'students'}
    __tablename__ = 'enrollments'
    # some Columns are defined here
```

I can use the `Base` instance to as `Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)` to recreate it in a test DB I have in postgres. I can confirm this was done without problems if I query the `pg_namespace`

```
In [111]: engine.execute("SELECT * FROM pg_namespace").fetchall()
2017-12-13 18:04:01,006 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT * FROM pg_namespace
2017-12-13 18:04:01,006 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}

Out[111]: 
[('pg_toast', 10, None),
 ('pg_temp_1', 10, None),
 ('pg_toast_temp_1', 10, None),
 ('pg_catalog', 10, '{postgres=UC/postgres,=U/postgres}'),
 ('public', 10, '{postgres=UC/postgres,=UC/postgres}'),
 ('information_schema', 10, '{postgres=UC/postgres,=U/postgres}'),
 ('schools', 16386, None),
 ('students', 16386, None)]
```

and from the psql CLI

```
user# select * from pg_tables;

     schemaname     |          tablename           | tableowner | tablespace | hasindexes | hasrules | hastriggers | rowsecurity 
--------------------+------------------------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------------
 schools            | addresses                    | diego      |            | t          | f        | f           | f
 students           | enrollments                  | diego      |            | t          | f        | f           | f
 pg_catalog         | pg_statistic                 | postgres   |            | t          | f        | f           | f
 pg_catalog         | pg_type                      | postgres   |            | t          | f        | f           | f
 pg_catalog         | pg_authid                    | postgres   | pg_global  | t          | f        | f           | f
 pg_catalog         | pg_user_mapping              | postgres   |            | t          | f        | f           | f
-- other tables were omitted
```

However, if I want to reflect that database in some other instance of `declarative_base` nothing is reflected.

Something like

```
In [87]: Base.metadata.tables.keys()
Out[87]: dict_keys(['schools.addresses', 'students.enrollments'])

In [88]: new_base = declarative_base()

In [89]: new_base.metadata.reflect(bind=engine)

In [90]: new_base.metadata.tables.keys()
Out[90]: dict_keys([])
```

I understand that `reflect` accepts a `schema` as a parameter but I would like to obtain all of them at once during reflection. For some reason I can achieve this one at a time.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you call `metadata.reflect()` it will only reflect the default schema (the first in your `search_path` for which you have permissions). So if your search_path is `public,students,school` it will only reflect the tables in schema `public`. If you do not have permissions on schema public, `public` schema will be skipped and will default to reflect only `students`.

The default schema is retrieved by `SELECT current_schema();`

In order to reflect other schemas
you need to call `metadata.reflect()` for each schema.

```py
metadata.reflect(schema='public')  # will reflect even if you do not have permissions on the tables in schema `public`, as long as you have access to pg_* system tables
metadata.reflect(schema='students')
metadata.reflect(schema='schools')
```

> Note: When you reflect with an explicit schema
>
> Reflected tables in `metadata.tables` will have the keys with the tables fully qualified schema name as in `schema1.mytable`, `schema2.mytable`
>
> Any conflicting table names will be replaced with the later one. If you have any tables with the same name, you should implement your the function `classname_for_table` to prefix the names with the schema name.

**An example of prefixing table names with the schema**

```
def classname_for_table(base, tablename, table):
    schema_name = table.schema
    fqname = '{}.{}'.format(schema_name, tablename)
    return fqname


Base.prepare(classname_for_table=classname_for_table)
```

**As a bonus, here is a small snippet which will expose all tables within a dynamic submodule per schema so you can access it **

create a file ie. *db.py* and place the following

```
from types import ModuleType


def register_classes(base, module_dict):
    for name, table in base.classes.items():
        schema_name, table_name = name.split('.')
        class_name = table_name.title().replace('_', '')
        if schema_name not in module_dict:
            module = module_dict[schema_name] = ModuleType(schema_name)
        else:
            module = module_dict[schema_name]
        setattr(module, class_name, table)
```

Call this function with the automap base and the `__dict__` of the module which you would like to register the schemas with.

```
 register_classes(base, globals())
```

or

```
import db
db.register_classes(base, db.__dict__)
```

and then you will get

```
import db
db.students.MyTable
db.schools.MyTable
```